# Como mostrar o cargar en un gridview el contenido de un textbox y/o combobox en C# Windows-Form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, combobox, gridview

[image: Esto es lo que he intentado por el momento, pero no resulta]

> Me ha habian dicho que utilize el DataRow, pero no se que es eso, la verdad estoy muy verde con esto de c#, si he llegado a ver DataSet antes pero no se si son exclusivos cuando utilizamos una base de datos, tambien creo que me falta la posicion en la que se insertarian los datos, pero no estoy seguro.

```
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Practicar_POO
{
    public partial class Practicas_Gridview : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public Practicas_Gridview()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a, b;

            a = cboNombres.Text;
            b = txtEdad.Text;

            gvPantalla.DataSource = a;
            gvPantalla.DataSource = b;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El datasource de una gridview puede ser cualquier objeto que sea iterable, por ejemplo una lista... que tal si creas una y pruebas pasarsela como DataSource?

Comment: Puedes pasarle un datatable a datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba asi:

```
     DataTable datos;//Creamos una tabla para que sirva de origen de datos

    public Practicas_Gridview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Instanciamos la tabla
        datos = new DataTable();
        //agregamos columnas
        datos.Columns.Add("Nombres");
        datos.Columns.Add("Edad");
        //le damos al data grid el origen de datos
        dataGridView1.DataSource = datos;
    }

    private void btnCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a, b;

        a = cboNombres.Text;
        b = txtEdad.Text;
        //agrega los datos a la tabla
        datos.Rows.Add(a, b);

    }
```